# Ext Js GUI Designer and Rails

Tags: extjs, gui-designer

I am new to using **Ext Js GUI Designer**. I have gone through some components. Are there any good tutorials or demos to understand the functionality of the same, and which can be implemented in Ruby On Rails?

Ref # http://www.projectspace.nl/

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS is client-site  JavaScript framework - it DOES NOT depend on server-side scripting language -> RoR is not a case

EDIT:

ExtJS Designer produce JavaScript code which need to be included in your pages...

Comment: Ok... so how to proceed with using the UI designer? Any references from where I can start as a beginner ?